# How can I suppress path expansion in the Git-for-Windows bash?

Tags: git-bash, git-for-windows

I'm struggling with Git-for-Windows bash: I try to exec into the shell of a kubernetes container, but git bash always prepends a windows path to the shell argument: `kubectl run test --image=alpine:latest -it /bin/sh` gets executed as `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\kubectl.exe" run test --image=alpine:latest -it "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh"`.

How can I prevent the expansion of the `/bin/sh` part? Quoting with single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) didn't help...

Answer (score 4):

Answers from **David Macek** and **Johannes Schindelin** in the [Git-for-Windows Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/git-for-windows/git#):

David Macek @elieux 18:51

Hi. Try `kubectl run test --image=alpine:latest -it //bin/sh`.
Otherwise see https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Porting/#filesystem-namespaces for MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL.

Johannes Schindelin @dscho 11:35

In Git for Windows, we have the more convenient `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV` variable, too, which is documented [in the Known Issues section of the Release Notes](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/49063144d88bf3fdd35e53eceb8cb973ecb3163c/ReleaseNotes.md?plain=1#L14).