# why aws cli log tail giving validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to connect to aws via aws cli through gossamer3 , but when I am trying to fetch running logs into my cmd prompt I am getting the following error. I am able to view the logs via cloudwatch in aws management console. But unable to bring the logs in the cmd prompt. In cloudwatch the path to the logs ->CloudWatch>Log groups>/aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa>/moa-ingestion-svc/moa-ingestion-svc/f184eed39ed94dc0b640eaae5e2c2aea

```
Log Configuration
Log driver: awslogs View logs in CloudWatch
Key                  Value
awslogs-group   /aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa
awslogs-region  us-east-1
awslogs-stream-prefix   /moa-ingestion-svc
```

But when I am trying to bring this via aws cli I am getting the following error. Anything wrong in my aws cli command

```
$ aws logs tail /aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa/moa-ingestion-svc/moa-ingestion-svc   --follow --since 10m --profile pub-mfa --region us-east-1

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the FilterLogEvents operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'C:/Program Files/Git/aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa/moa-ingestion-svc/moa-ingestion-svc' at 'logGroupName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the (shorter) group name `/aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa` and add `--log-stream-name-prefix /moa-ingestion-svc` (or some variant thereof).

Comment: $  aws logs tail /aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa --log-stream-name-prefix /moa-ingestion-svc --follow --since 10m --profile pub-mfa --region us-east-1

Unknown options: --log-stream-name-prefix,C:/Program Files/Git/moa-ingestion-svc

Comment: Run `aws logs tail help` to get the command line options. It shows `[--log-stream-name-prefix <value>]` here with aws-cli/2.11.2.

Comment: The error `Value 'C:/Program Files/Git` is telling.  What shell are you using?  It appears to be turning `/aws...` into `C:/Program Files/Git/aws...`  Perhaps adding `"` or `'` around the log group name will prevent this behavior.

Comment: Looks like git-bash expansion on Windows. I can repro. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341356/how-can-i-suppress-path-expansion-in-the-git-for-windows-bash).

Comment: Run `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws logs tail /aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa/...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be running git bash on Windows, which is expanding the provided log group name as if it were a local folder name.

To fix this, disable expansion as follows:

```
$ MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws logs tail /aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa/...
```

Also, at least in the awscli version aws-cli/2.11.2 that I am running, the log group name and log stream prefix are supplied independently, as follows:

```
aws logs tail <group_name> --log-stream-name-prefix <value>
```

Comment: $  MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws logs tail /aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa/moa-ingestion-svc/moa-ingestion-svc --follow --since 10m --profile pub-mfa --region us-east-1

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the FilterLogEvents operation: The specified log group does not exist.

Comment: It worked !!!MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws logs tail /aws/ecs/oa/moa/qa --follow --since 10m --profile pub-mfa --region us-east-1....I am using 2.1.24...does it have log-stream-name-prefix attribute?

Comment: You can run`aws logs tail help` to get the command line options and see if your version supports `--log-stream-name-prefix`.